# Image reconstruction using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I tried reconstructing an image from its magnitude and phase components, but all I get is a black screen output. I actually got the magnitude spectrum by using fft2(f), fftshift(f) taking abs, then log(f+1) then converting mat2gray(f). I edited this magnitude spectrum image using an editor to remove few noise frequencies in the spectrum. Now I want to reconstruct my image, please help me out with a code that reconstructs the image without a black screen as output.

Comment: Show some of your own code, if you will.

Answer (score 0):

You need to to use

> newImage = ifftshift (image);

Followed by:

> newImage = ifft2 (newImage);